# Which crypto-currency has the most even distribution of wealth?

Tags: alternatives, currencies

Bitcoin, Ripple, PPCoin, Freicoin and most other cryptocurrencies have a significant portion of the currency in the hands of early adopters or a central group charged with 'distributing' the currency. Does anyone know which has been the most successful at distributing the coins evenly?

Thanks

Comment: Can't be answered, except maybe for ripple.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to track how many coins are owned by a given address, but there's no way (at least, no *easy* way) to associate an address with its actual owner; it's not possible to know for sure how wealth is distributed.

Comment: indeed it's impossible to say; on one hand, coins on one address may actually belong to multiple people (in the case of online wallets and exchanges), on the other hand, multiple addresses can belong to one wallet and to one person